# Is there a way to split a string by multiple parameters and not get TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

Tags: python, split

Is there a way to split a string by multiple parameters? When I try it the way I've got below, I get

```py
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Looking into it, it should work.

The program is a translator to a new language, etc. **man** is masculine so **the man** is **de mno** while **woman** which is feminine would be **di felio** instead of **de felio**. I've got everything working up to this point, and I want to start working on rearranging the sentence order. I want to be able to split at every **de** and **di**, not just one of them. I've looked online and tried using a solution I found using the `re` module but it didn't end up working.

```
new_sentence = re.split(' de', ' di', translated_sentence)
print(new_sentence)
```

When I print `new_sentence`, if I entered originally and already translated `the man is with the woman` into `de mno aili di felio`. I want it to print out like `['de mno aili', 'di felio']`.

I don't have a very good understanding of the split function so my code may be completely wrong.

Comment: Your error in this case is incorrect use of re.split, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).  But the answer below covers how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the space, and use a character class `d[ei]` to match either de or di with a regex. If you don't want a partial match, you can add a word boundary `\b` at the end.

```
import re
translated_sentence = "The program is a translator to a new language, etc. man is masculine so the man is de mno while woman which is feminine would be di felio instead of de felio."

new_sentence = re.split(r' d[ei]\b', translated_sentence)

print(new_sentence)
```

Output

```
['The program is a translator to a new language, etc. man is masculine so the man is', ' mno while woman which is feminine would be', ' felio instead of', ' felio.']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/p2y8gs)

Comment: It gives me TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' when I enter that

Comment: @qwerteee There is no TypeError in the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/p2y8gs)

Comment: yeah thanks, entered it in wrong

Comment: is there a way to split it and keep the original 'de' and 'di'? for example, I split it and after more code to rearrange the order it keeps the first article ('de' or 'di') and rearranges it but the second one, eg the 'the' before woman in 'the man is with the woman' doesn't get kept.

Comment: @qwerteee You can keep the values to split on using a capture group for the regex, see https://ideone.com/JFSOg0. If you want to keep them as part of the text, you can use a lookahead https://ideone.com/KCgTsV

Answer (score 1):

If you have list of elements which should split, you might use `re.escape` and `|` to craft pattern from that which might be then used as `re.split` 1st argument, consider following example

```
import re
splitat = ['da','di','do']
pattern = '|'.join(re.escape(i) for i in splitat)
text = 'Some do text di for da testing'
print(re.split(pattern,text))
```

output

```
['Some ', ' text ', ' for ', ' testing']
```

`re.escape` does take care of any character which have special meaning in patterns.